# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: The object is already closed [90007-200]

Tags: java, mysql, h2

Bump into this error from h2 database its working ok till now i understand the connection is closed how to prevent this.

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: The object is already closed [90007-200]

```
    ResultSet rest = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM monthly_summary WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM monthly_summary);");
    rest.next();
    if(rest.getInt(3) == month && rset.getInt(4) == year) {
        double oldAmount = rest.getDouble(2);
        st.execute("UPDATE monthly_summary SET amount =" + (oldAmount + amount)  + ";");
    } else {
        st.execute("INSERT INTO monthly_summary(amount, `month`, `year`) VALUES (" + amount + "," + month + "," + year + ");");
    }
```

Comment: This link should help you understand how `ResultSet.next()` behaves. [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java-resultset-next-method-with-example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java-resultset-next-method-with-example)

Answer (score 0):

The `ResultSet::next` needs to be in the `if` statement:

```java
ResultSet rest = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM monthly_summary WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM monthly_summary);");
if (rest.next()) {
    if(rest.getInt(3) == month && rset.getInt(4) == year) {
        double oldAmount = rest.getDouble(2);
        st.execute("UPDATE monthly_summary SET amount =" + (oldAmount + amount)  + ";");
    } else {
        st.execute("INSERT INTO monthly_summary(amount, `month`, `year`) VALUES (" + amount + "," + month + "," + year + ");");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how exactly does this code fix the issue.

Comment: I am not very sure how to explain just ResultSet need to be in if statement Is very common mistake.If you have better explanation I will be glad to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The exception with message

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: The object is already closed [90007-200]

(or here the German version: `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Das Objekt wurde bereits geschlossen`, `The object is already closed [90007-200]`)

happens if you try to use a `Connection` that is already closed. "Closing" can occur explicitly by calling `connection.close()` and it can occur implicitly at the end of a `try(Connection connection = ...) {...}` block.

You can check whether your `Connection` is already closed with this: `connection.isClosed()`.